# How to analyze what is wrong with xdebug

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm

I've read few tutorials about how to configure remote debugging with xdebug and phpstorm. I'm quite sure that I've done everything right. Is it possible to check if xdebug on remote server works well? Is there any log or something like this?

On localhost it works great, the problem is only with remote.

Comment: No, there is no log. Either it works or it does not work. What else do you want to test?

Comment: Can I test if the problem is with remote server, local php interpreter (and xdebug) or with my phpstorm configuration?

Comment: *"Is there any log or something like this?"* **xdebug.remote_log** ?? http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log . **ALSO:** `phpinfo();` and check output (if xdebug is loaded; what config values is has etc).

Comment: I've finally solved my problem. I forgot to forward port 9000 on router to my ip.